# How to run a docker container with a previously determined ip address with the python docker sdk?

Tags: python, docker

On console this does the trick:

```
docker run --net mynet --ip 172.18.0.22 --dns="8.8.8.8" -d testimage
```

is there an easy equivalent with the python docker sdk like this?

```
container = client.containers.run("alpine", "ls /", detach=True, ipv4_address=ip_address)
```

but there is no ipv4_address param in the run function...

Comment: That IP address is all but useless; you can't reach it from another host, or if Docker Desktop or a similar VM-based solution is in use, or in some other reasonably common circumstances.  I'd just delete the option from the `docker run` command and not worry about it in your docker-py invocation.

Comment: If I can determine the IP I can add firewall routings on that container. That's why I need to know the IP in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address of a container only exists in reference to whichever network the container is being connected to at that IP, so you need to specify it on the network connection, not container creation.

This becomes a two-step process in the Python SDK. Assuming the network `mynet` already exists, you can connect your container to it after creation using [`Network.connect`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/networks.html#docker.models.networks.Network.connect). The equivalent of your console command would be something like:

```py
container = client.containers.run("testimage", detach=True, dns=["8.8.8.8"])
mynet = client.networks.list(names=["mynet"])[0]
mynet.connect(container, ipv4_address="172.18.0.22")
```